# How to get the constraints allowed list of values in alfresco Java API

Tags: alfresco

I need to get the constraints parameter list of allowed values from the property in model. Below is the model which has the namespace as `custom` and property name as `common`. I have tried with below Java webscript, but it is not working, I get an empty list

**Model snippet:**

```
 <namespaces>
   <namespace uri="custom" prefix="custom"/>
 </namespaces>
 <property name="custom:common">
    <title>common</title>
    <type>d:text</type>
    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
    <index enabled="true">
      <tokenised>TRUE</tokenised>
      <facetable>false</facetable>
    </index>
    <constraints>
      <constraint name="custom:LIST_6f4ee71b-0c8c-4f79-805f-a8d1065ae0b9" type="LIST">
        <parameter name="allowedValues">
          <list>
            <value>Select</value>
            <value>Unit1</value>
            <value>Unit2</value>
          </list>
        </parameter>
      </constraint>
    </constraints>
</property>
```

**Java:**

```
QName qName = null;
qName.createQName("custom", "custom:common");
Object list = this.serviceRegistry.getDictionaryService().getConstraint(qName).getConstraint().getParameters().get(ListOfValuesConstraint.ALLOWED_VALUES_PARAM);
```

Comment: Don't you need to get the definition of the property `custom:custom`, then get the constraints off that? You appear to be trying to directly fetch a constraint called `custom:custom` which won't work as that's the property name